# When do I init the variables in Custom create function with argument in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have create a custom Layer and I want to pass two variables in to this layer. Should I init `Tlayer` and `Hlayer` in constructor function or in `init()` function? I have check some materials and most says that we should avoid to use constructor function. Why?

```
TouchLayer* TouchLayer::create(TcharacterLayer* t,HcharacterLayer* h){
    TouchLayer* pRet = new TouchLayer();
    if (pRet && pRet->init())
    {
        pRet->autorelease();
        return pRet;
    }else
    {
        delete pRet;
        pRet = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
}

class TouchLayer : public CCLayerColor
{
public:
    TouchLayer();
    ~TouchLayer();
    virtual bool init();
    virtual void onEnter();
    virtual void onExit();
    CREATE_FUNC(TouchLayer);
    static TouchLayer* create(TcharacterLayer* t,HcharacterLayer* h);

    TcharacterLayer* Tlayer;
    HcharacterLayer* Hlayer;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get some relate information about "why we should use init() method instead of constructor" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20280664/3090526

Answer (score 0):

- If your class has only one constructor, you can init your class's member in the constructor.
- But if you have multiple constructor then i think you should init your class's member in `init()` function because if not you must to init your class member in each constructor and you may miss to init some member.
- If you use a modern compiler, you can use `Delegating constructors` and don't need to write `init()` function.

[Delegating constructors - gcc 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should assign those variables after line `TouchLayer* pRet = new TouchLayer();` in your static `create` method. e.g. :

```
pRet->Tlayer  = t;
pRet->Hlayer  = h;
```