# Cocos2d-x crashes after a few seconds or minutes

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

A game developed using Cocos2d-x crashes after a few minutes of using it. This error doesn't happen in iOS, but in Android occurs in Dalvik and in ART, no matter the device and no matter the Android version.

A read a lot of in depth here but I found no answer.

It looks like a memory leak but I'm no sure about it. This game has a lot of resources and depending on the device it takes more or less time to crash. All is related with de evil's signal 3 which Dalvik and ART send to the App because it doesn't answer and the generated report has no sense.

Ah, it always happen when a sprite goes to notVisible, but it occurs randomly.

Can I configure the memory management of Cocos2d-x? Can I configure Dalvik's garbage collector?

Any idea to began with?

Thanks in advance.

Thats the Cocos2d-x output report (edited to be an interesting person)

```
Crash dump is completed

********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:4.4.4/KTU84P/1227136:user/release-keys'
pid: 26249, tid: 26287, name: Thread-5259  >>> jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
Stack frame #00  pc 000116cc  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1191)
Stack frame #01  pc 0000dc0b  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
Stack frame #02  pc 0020dd13  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCComponentContainer::~CCComponentContainer()+10): Routine ~CCComponentContainer at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/support/component/CCComponentContainer.cpp:41 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #03  pc 001dd3f1  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCNode::~CCNode()+220): Routine ~CCNode at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/base_nodes/CCNode.cpp:143 (discriminator 2)
Stack frame #04  pc 001894d9  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (StoreListCell::~StoreListCell()+28): Routine ~CCTableViewCell at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/extensions/GUI/CCScrollView/CCTableViewCell.h:37 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #05  pc 00189501  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (StoreListCell::~StoreListCell()+4): Routine ~StoreListCell at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/jni/../../Classes/Game/StoreListCell.cpp:114
Stack frame #06  pc 001e07b5  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCObject::release()+16): Routine cocos2d::CCObject::release() at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCObject.cpp:86 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #07  pc 00208897  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::ccArrayRemoveAllObjects(cocos2d::_ccArray*)+16): Routine cocos2d::ccArrayRemoveAllObjects(cocos2d::_ccArray*) at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/support/data_support/ccCArray.cpp:188
Stack frame #08  pc 002088ad  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::ccArrayFree(cocos2d::_ccArray*&)+10): Routine cocos2d::ccArrayFree(cocos2d::_ccArray*&) at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/support/data_support/ccCArray.cpp:52
Stack frame #09  pc 001e0ffd  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCArray::~CCArray()+16): Routine ~CCArray at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCArray.cpp:374
Stack frame #10  pc 001e1015  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCArray::~CCArray()+4): Routine ~CCArray at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCArray.cpp:375
Stack frame #11  pc 001e07b5  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCObject::release()+16): Routine cocos2d::CCObject::release() at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCObject.cpp:86 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #12  pc 001dd3d7  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCNode::~CCNode()+194): Routine ~CCNode at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/base_nodes/CCNode.cpp:139 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #13  pc 001ee9df  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCLayer::~CCLayer()+78): Routine ~CCLayer at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/layers_scenes_transitions_nodes/CCLayer.cpp:64
Stack frame #14  pc 001eec1d  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCLayer::~CCLayer()+4): Routine ~CCLayer at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/layers_scenes_transitions_nodes/CCLayer.cpp:64
Stack frame #15  pc 001e07b5  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCObject::release()+16): Routine cocos2d::CCObject::release() at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCObject.cpp:86 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #16  pc 00208897  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::ccArrayRemoveAllObjects(cocos2d::_ccArray*)+16): Routine cocos2d::ccArrayRemoveAllObjects(cocos2d::_ccArray*) at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/support/data_support/ccCArray.cpp:188
Stack frame #17  pc 002088ad  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::ccArrayFree(cocos2d::_ccArray*&)+10): Routine cocos2d::ccArrayFree(cocos2d::_ccArray*&) at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/support/data_support/ccCArray.cpp:52
Stack frame #18  pc 001e0ffd  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCArray::~CCArray()+16): Routine ~CCArray at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCArray.cpp:374
Stack frame #19  pc 001e1015  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCArray::~CCArray()+4): Routine ~CCArray at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCArray.cpp:375
Stack frame #20  pc 001e07b5  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCObject::release()+16): Routine cocos2d::CCObject::release() at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/cocoa/CCObject.cpp:86 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #21  pc 001dd3d7  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCNode::~CCNode()+194): Routine ~CCNode at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/base_nodes/CCNode.cpp:139 (discriminator 1)
Stack frame #22  pc 001ee9df  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::CCLayer::~CCLayer()+78): Routine ~CCLayer at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/cocos2dx/layers_scenes_transitions_nodes/CCLayer.cpp:64
Stack frame #23  pc 001b1ac5  /data/app-lib/jp.co.secretcompany.misteriousname-1/libgame.so (cocos2d::extension::CCScrollView::~CCScrollView()+60): Routine ~CCScrollView at /Users/misterunknow/Documents/secretcompany/misteriousname/Project/android/../libs/extensions/GUI/CCScrollView/CCScrollView.cpp:65
```

Comment: Can you post logcat's log and line of codes too where it crashes?

Comment: There are no LogCat stuff... but I got the crash report of Cocos and I will update the post.

Comment: It points to a class' destructor but... this destructor is empty, as all of the others that never crashed.

Comment: I have described it in more detail, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the problem seems related with a bug handling CCLabelTTF on early versions of Cocos2d-x, specially if you use weird chars and fonts, e.g. Japanese.

It provokes randomly crashes if you allocate a lot of labels, in that case, in a scrolled table.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem in our first game and issue was

> We were not releasing objects we were retaining.

After some time it crashes due to memory error. Check to see your objects are being destroyed once your are done with that scene or layer. I prefer to use CCSprite:create method because it creates a auto release object and you don't have to worry about releasing it manually.

Here are some links to give you more insight about it.

[Cocos2dx memory management, how to use destructors and when to release obejcts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036887/cocos2dx-memory-management-how-to-use-destructors-and-when-to-release-obejcts)

[Memory deallocation in Cocos2d-x](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/memory-deallocation-in-cocos2d-x/137)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but in this game all Cocos Objects are autoreleased and it still crush in a destructor autocalled by the Cocos garbage collector.

Comment: It's about thousands of lines of code, from here to the sun. I only need some hints to find it out. Share code has no sense in this case.

Comment: As you wish. But without code I'm not sure all of your code is properly auto released because if it were, There won't be a error like you describing. Can you share "/Game/StoreListCell.cpp:114" Or better StoreListCell? I'm not asking to share your whole project.

Comment: That line is the destructor, and is empty, so I don't know where to search more

`StoreListCell::~StoreListCell(){
    
}`

Constructor is also empty.

AH! And is a CCTableViewCell object.