# How to destroy items in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I can create a menu by doing:

```
Menu* menu = Menu::createWithArray(vectorOfItems);
```

But how do I destroy it? Is it as simple as doing:

```
menu->removeFromParent(true);
menu = std::null_ptr;
```

And then can I reuse it by doing this?:

```
menu = Menu::createWithArray(anothervectorOfItems);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can destroy menu by `menu->removeFromParent(true);` and reuse by doing that. If you don't use `foo->retain()`, you don't need to use `foo->release()` generaly.
Cocos2d-x use referrence counting by default. Most `create` functions returns an auto-release object.
[Cocos2dx memory management, how to use destructors and when to release obejcts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036887/cocos2dx-memory-management-how-to-use-destructors-and-when-to-release-obejcts)